# Logging custom properties in Python

Tags: c#, python, logging, log4net

In log4net I can add a custom property to the thread context like this:

```
ThreadContext.Properties["UserName"] = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
```

I can then customize the format string to output this property in the log like this:

```
"%property{UserName}"
```

What would the equivalent of this be in the python logging framework?

Answer (score 0):

To add contextual information to logs with Python, you would use a `LoggerAdapter`, a `Filter` or include the information in a logging call using an `extra` keyword parameter. See [this section](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output) of the documentation for more details.